# Can Isomorphism between categories be defined only if both categories are small?

Tags: category-theory

In wikipedia page, "[Isomorphism of categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_of_categories)
",

> A functor F : C → D yields an isomorphism of categories if and only if
>   it is bijective on objects and on morphism sets.

I have heard that bijection or "morphism sets" can be defined only if the category is small. "Category isomorphism" can be only if the both categories are small?

Comment: Morphism sets $\to$ locally small. I'm pretty sure this is not required though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. But the answer in detail depends on the foundations you are using. For instance, in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ we may interpret classes using formulas (up to equivalence). Then, a category $C$ has a formula $\mathrm{Ob}(C)$ with one variable such that "$x$ is an object of $C$" means that $\mathrm{Ob}(C)(x)$ holds. Also, we have formulas $\mathrm{Mor}(C)$, $\mathrm{dom}(C)$, $\mathrm{cod}(C)$, $\mathrm{Comp}(C)$, $\mathrm{Id}(C)$ such that the category axioms are satisfied. Now, a functor $F : C \to D$ consists of two formulas $F_O$ and $F_M$ such that

- $\forall x ( \mathrm{Ob}(C)(x) \Rightarrow \exists ! y (\mathrm{Ob}(D)(y) \wedge  F_O(x,y))$

i.e., every object of $C$ is mapped to some specified object of $D$; one usually writes $F(x)=y$ instead of $F_O(x,y)$. Likewise for morphisms:

- $\forall f (\mathrm{Mor}(C)(f) \Rightarrow \exists ! g ( \mathrm{Mor}(D)(g) \wedge  F_M(f,g))$
- $\forall f,g,x,x',y,y' (F_M(f,g) \wedge \mathrm{dom}(C)(f,x) \wedge \mathrm{cod}(C)(f,x') \wedge F_O(x,y) \wedge F_O(x',y') \Rightarrow \mathrm{dom}(D)(g,y) \wedge \mathrm{cod}(D)(g,y'))$

i.e., if $f$ is a morphism in $C$ from $x$ to $x'$, then $F(f)$ is a morphism in $D$ from $F(x)$ to $F(x')$,

- compabilities with respect to identities and composition (which I won't write down here).

The composition of two functors $F : C \to D$, $G : D \to E$ is the functor $G \circ F : C \to E$ defined by $(G \circ F)_O(x,z) :\Leftrightarrow \exists y (F_O(x,y) \wedge G_O(y,z))$, likewise for $(G \circ F)_M$.

Now, $F$ is an isomorphism iff $F_O$ and $F_M$ are bijective, i.e.

- $\forall y ( \mathrm{Ob}(D)(y) \Rightarrow \exists ! x (\mathrm{Ob}(C)(x) \wedge  F_O(x,y))$
- $\forall g (\mathrm{Mor}(D)(g) \Rightarrow \exists ! f ( \mathrm{Mor}(C)(f) \wedge F_M(f,g))$

In this case, the inverse functor $F^{-1}$ is defined by $F^{-1}_O(y,x)  :\Leftrightarrow F_O(x,y)$ and $F^{-1}_M(g,f) :\Leftrightarrow F_M(f,g)$.

Comment: This is instructive, +1. The problem is not in question what _isomorphism_ is, it is, as always, defined as invertible morphism. The real question is what _functor_ is.

Answer (score 4):

Bijections can also be defined on proper classes. 
So it doesn't matter if the category is (locally) small.

Comment: I'd appreciate some details here on how exactly one handles bijections of classes in ZFC.

Comment: A proper class $C$ in ZFC is a defined by a formula with parameters: $x\in C := \phi(x, \vec{a})$. Similarly, a proper class bijection $F$ is defined by a formula: $F(x) = y := \beta(x,y)$ (omitting possible parameters) that's 'single-valued". So, for proper classes $C,D$,  and a proper class bijection $F$, to say that "$F$ is a bijection between $C$ and $D$" is just a formula of ZFC. // Or, you can work in von Neumann-Godel-Bernays set theory, or in Kelley-Morse (KM) set theory, both of which allow quantification over proper classes. // Or, finally, adopt Tarski's Axiom = Axiom of Universes..

Comment: The Axiom of Universes guarantees that (a little loosely speaking) whatever the categories, you can always ascend to a larger universe in which those categories are small.